# Weird behaviour from Pulseaudio

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, pulseaudio-equalizer

There is no output from my headphone. But when I unlock the front panel and adjust either the front-left or front right, there's sound coming out. And the audio output is the loudest when the difference in value between front-left and front-right is the largest. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Guess: Your headphone somehow picks up the left channel and right channel as signal and ground, instead of the the common ground as ground.

Note the [pinout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#Design) for headphone jacks, and the difference between mono and stereo.

If you have a multimeter or similar, measure to confirm.

If you cannot fix the hardware, you could workaround in Pulseaudio by mixing front-left and front-right to a single channel, and forcing the other channel to zero, using a [Pulseaudio module](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/).

Comment: Thanks for your effort buddy!

Comment: I have been using my headphone for quite a while without a single problem. This problem came up suddenly a few days ago. I have no idea as to how did this weird behavior come up. Anyway, I guess either something within the headphone is faulty, cause I have plugged it into my smartphone, and the same thing happened. I will definitely look into the solution you provided. Thanks!

Comment: If the same thing happens in your Smartphone, I guess some of the cabling in the headphone either is loose or has a short, and that causes the "signal gets picked up between left and right channel" behaviour.